# The Jacquet module of the Steinberg Representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I have also posted this question also on Math Stack Exchange, please inform me if the level is too low for this forum.

Let $G=GL_2(F)$ where $F$ is a non-Archimedean local field of characteristic $0$, for example $\mathbb{Q_p}$. Let $\chi=1_T$ be the trivial character of the maximal split torus $T=\begin{pmatrix}* & 0 \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix}$ of $G$. We can smoothly induct $1_T$ to a representation of $G$, we call this $\text{Ind}1_T$. By the irreducibility criterion (lemma 9.6 of "The Local Langlands Conjecture for GL(2)" by Bushnell and Henniart), the smooth representation $\text{Ind}1_T$ has $G$-length 2, and a one-dimensional $G$-subspace which carries the trivial character $1_G=1_T \circ \det.$ We call the irreducible $G$-quotient of $\text{Ind}1_T$ the Steinberg representation, and denote it by $St_G$. I am trying to see why, in this case, $(St_G)_N\simeq\delta_B^{-1}$ where $\delta_B$ is the module character of $B$, and $(St_G)_N$ the Jacquet module of $St_G$ at $N$.

I know that there is an exact sequence
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow 1_G \rightarrow \text{Ind}1_T \rightarrow St_G \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
hence after applying the exact Jacquet functor, and noting $1_T=(1_G)_N$, we get
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow 1_T \rightarrow (\text{Ind}1_T)_N \rightarrow (St_G)_N \rightarrow 0.
\end{equation}

Also, by the induction-restriction lemma of the same book mentioned above, the Jacquet module of $\text{Ind}1_T$ fits into the following exact sequence:
\begin{equation}
0 \rightarrow \delta_B^{-1} \rightarrow (\text{Ind}1_T)_N \rightarrow 1_T \rightarrow 0.
\end{equation}
I'm missing how to conclude from here that $(St_G)_N$ and $\delta_B^{-1}$ are isomorphic. Beyond that, I know the Steinberg representation is important in this context, but I don't really see why yet so a word on its importance/significance would be appreciated.

Comment: i think it is just that the T module is semi-simple so the module in the middle is a direct sum of two one dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Exactly. Since T is a torus, there are no nontrivial extensions between distinct irreducible representations.

Comment: Is a smooth representation of an abelian group always semi-simple? Or does something else tell you $\text{Ind} 1_T$ is semi-simple?

Comment: @Venkataramana: forgot to tag with the above question. Could you clarify the claim that the T module is semi-simple.

Comment: "Is a smooth representation of an abelian group always semi-simple"? No, clearly not; a finite-length smooth representation of the discrete group $\mathbf{Z}$ is just an invertible matrix, and there are plenty of non-diagonalisable matrices! But a matrix with *distinct eigenvalues* is diagonalisable, and that's the statement you need here